# How to extract data points from an image of a graph using Python

Tags: python, graph

I want to extract data points from a graph that is taken from the specification of a Si-photodiode, as you can see from the graph, the graph shows the sensitivity of the diode in some spectral ranges, I need to get the value of the sensitivity at the wavelength of 336 nm, is there any way to do that in Python? I saw a video that describes the similar feature of Matlab: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9P3PVLjW0bw, it would be very useful if someone could give some tips or suggestions about how to do that in Python.[image]

Comment: What format do you have your graph in ?

Comment: this graph has the .jpg format.